# How do I copy a list and then replace the characters?

Tags: python, list

I am looking to copy a list that I have in python and then replace the characters.

For example:

If the code asks you to input a word: (and you type) 'hello'

'hello' will get added to a list.

what I want to do is copy that list and then replace 'hello' with '*****'
and i want the '*' to be the same index as the 'hello' index.

Thanks!

ps. I think my actual code is irrelevant, I just need a basic understanding.

edit:

```
import getpass

hangman_pics = ['''
    +---+
        |
        |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
        |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
    |   |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|   |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|\  |
        |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|\  |
   /    |
       ===''','''
    +---+
    O   |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
       ===''']

let_list = []
alreadyGuessed = []
correctGuessed = []
falseGuessed = []
lettersLeft = []

def player_input():
    word_input = getpass.getpass("Choose the word: ")
    for letter in word_input:
        let_list.append(letter)


def player_guess():
    while let_list:
        print ("Please enter your guess: ")
        guess = input()
        if guess in let_list:
            if guess in alreadyGuessed:
                print ('Oops, you already guessed ' + guess)
            else:
                alreadyGuessed.append(guess)
                correctGuessed.append(guess)
                print (guess + ' is correct!')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print ('Oops, you already guessed ' + guess)
        else:
            alreadyGuessed.append(guess)
            falseGuessed.append(guess)
            print (guess + ' is wrong, sorry')
        while set(let_list) == set(correctGuessed):
            print ('Congratulations! You win!')
            return False
            break
        while len(falseGuessed) == len(hangman_pics):
            print ('Oh no, you killed him! You lose :(')
            return False
            break





player_input()
player_guess()
```

Comment: that's unclear. Can you post what you're expecting as a python list?

Comment: Your code isn't irrelevant - it gives a better understanding to what you're trying to achieve. And if code is irrelevant - does that mean there's no point in someone providing it as an answer? :p

Comment: Why you want to copy and replace? Instead you can get length(n) and add nX *  to the list .

Comment: Are you sure it's a list, and not just a plain string?

Comment: I did? didnt I? I'm expecting a list contained with letters like ['h','e','l','l','o'] to print like ['*','*','*','*','*']... is that clear enough?

Comment: @JosephCranney no. Btw it wasn't me who downvoted you.

Comment: I want lettersLeft to be the list that has the *****

Comment: yup - figured you were trying to write a hangman game :)

Comment: look at producing a [mcve] for what you're actually asking and are having problems with.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre bro, I don't know, thats why I am asking....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` function in python; for example,

```
test = ['h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
def your_logic(element):
    if condition:
        return "*"
    return element

# every element in the list will be converted using your condition
result_list = map(your_logic, test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = []
for word in list1:
    if word == "hello":
        list2.append("*****")
    else:
        list2.append(word)
```

Comment: And where is `list2` defined?

Comment: Updated to reflect that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write this as `list2 = ['*****' if word == 'hello' else word for word in list1]`?

Comment: Because it's evident that's he's new to Python, and expanded syntax is typically easier to follow for novices.

Comment: True, but the question statement and the actual result in comments don't seem to match - there's not really an answerable question here unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It is quite ambiguous, isn't it?

Comment: look guys, I'm new and all, can you just help instead of blocking me for 4 days? I really need this site for help...